# how to delete post from firebase? Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying a lot of things and I have been searching a lot on the internet but I can't find a solution that helps me because of how my code is set up.

Any how I have been trying to delete posts but I don't really know how to do this since my posts are uploaded in a Auto Id generated by firebase and I dont know what to write here

```
Database.database().reference.child("posts").child("HERE IS THE AUTO ID").removeValue
```

How do I get this? Please help me I have been stuck for this problem a while now.
I have no clue how to get the autoid.

this is how I upload the post

```
   if (self.imageFileName != "") {
        if choosenCountryLabel.text == "Albania" {
            // image has finshed the uploading, Saving Post!!!
            if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {

                Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        for user in userDictionary{
                            if let username = user.value as? String {
                                if let streetAdress = self.locationAdressTextField.text {
                                    if let title = self.titleTextField.text {
                                        if let content = self.contentTextView.text {
                                            let postObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                                                "uid" : uid,
                                                "title" : title,
                                                "content" : content,
                                                "username" : username,
                                                "time" : self.timeStamps,
                                                "timeorder" : self.secondTimeStamps,
                                                "image" : self.imageFileName,
                                                "adress" : streetAdress,
                                                "postAutoID" : self.postAutoID
                                            ]


                                            let postID = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()
                                            let postID2 = Database.database().reference().child("AlbaniaPosts").childByAutoId()
                                            let postID3 = Database.database().reference().child(uid).childByAutoId()

                                            postID.setValue(postObject)
                                            postID2.setValue(postObject)
                                            postID3.setValue(postObject)
                                            let postAutoID = postID.key
                                            let postAutoID2 = postID2.key
                                            let postAutoID3 = postID3.key
                                            print(postAutoID)
                                            print(postAutoID2)
                                            print(postAutoID3)

                                            let alertPosting = UIAlertController(title: "Successfull upload", message: "Your acty was successfully uploaded.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                            alertPosting.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                                                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AlbaniaVC")
                                                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                            }))
                                            self.present(alertPosting, animated: true, completion: nil)



                                            print("Posted Succesfully to Firebase, Saving Post!!!")

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }

        }
    }else{
        let alertNotPosting = UIAlertController(title: "Seems like you got connection problems", message: "Your image has not been uploaded. Please Wait 10 seconds and try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertNotPosting.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alertNotPosting, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[image: and here is the query in firebase.]

Comment: Quick question: How will the user know which post he is deleting?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes on each post you can swipe from right to left to delete a spesific post

Comment: Can you post the code you use for the "swipe to delete"? It might be easier to help you from there

Comment: I dont have anything set up only thing i have fixad now is that the user can swipe and get a delete Button like the normal swipe to delete on a normal tableview i only need to know How to reach the autoid in My database @RosárioPereiraFernandes

Comment: the autoId is the key before the post, so for AlbianiaPost it is the "-L1Detc", when you retrieve the posts from Firebase, you get the key (autoId) and the value (post).

Comment: @PeterdeVries yes i know this but i dont know How to reach it progrommaticly so that the user can delete his own posts

Comment: You are retrieving the post with if "let userDictionary = snapshot.value", the key (autoId) is "snapshot.key". But you are confusing uploading a post ("updateChildValues()" and retrieving a post (with "observeSingleEvent")

Comment: Okey so IF i get this right i can do `print(snapshot.key)` and and the auto generated id that was generated by firebase will print in My console? IF so then that is a possible way i could reach for it@PeterdeVries

Answer (score 0):

[Delete data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data)

> The simplest way to delete data is to call remove() on a reference to
>   the location of that data.
>
> You can also delete by specifying null as the value for another write
>   operation such as set() or update(). You can use this technique with
>   update() to delete multiple children in a single API call.

Comment: Yes Thanks for the tips but i dont know How i can get the autoid for a specific row progrommaticlly

Comment: Do you know How to reach through posts and then the auto generated id?

Comment: put the key name in the HTML as a [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on whatever element you allow to be deleted.

Comment: Yes but it is Swift and it is auto generated so the user and i can not know What the key is If you dont look at the database

Comment: your initially getting the data from the db to built the HTML, right? If so, the key is provided then, that's when you can get it.

Comment: The key is provided to My posts array, but i want to delete it directly from the database, i know How to do that but i have been stuck on How to get the hold of posts specefic post auto generated id

Comment: I see, you are initially getting the key in your array. Can you not apply a property to your view element(s) containing the key?

Comment: Yes i could do that but i think the post Will only get deleted from the array and not the database, and maybe it Will still not actually get deleted sence My array fetching everything from posts to the array

Comment: you have to script that database `.remove()` to happen upon swipe/delete UI event.

Comment: Yes i know but the problem is i dont know How to get get the auto generated id

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the autoID when you query your data or you have to save the key inside the post when you upload it.

If want to get the key when you query. You can do something like this:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("posts").queryLimited(toLast: 7).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
    for child in snap.children {
        let child = child as? DataSnapshot
        if let key = child?.key { // save this value in your post object
            if let post = child?.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                if let adress = post["adress"] as? String, let title = post["title"] as? String { // add the rest of your data
                    // create an object and store in your data array
                }            
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Note the above query only gets the last 7 posts. If you want to continue to get more you'll need to look into [pagination](https://medium.com/@wcandillon/firebase-live-pagination-474748853e52).

If you want to save the id in your posts you just add it when you upload like this:

```
let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key

let post = ["adress": adress,
            "content": content,
            "postID": key] as [String: Any]

let postFeed = ["\(key)" : feed]

ref.child("posts").updateChildValues(postFeed, withCompletionBlock: { (error, success) in
    if error != nil {
        // report the error
    }
    else {
        // everything is fine
    }
})
```

Then when you query you can do something like this:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("posts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
    for child in snap.children {
        if let post = child?.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let postID = post["postID"] as? String {
                // save this key in a post object so you can access it later to delete
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Now assuming you created an object called post you can delete that post using

```
ref.child("posts").child(post.postID).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, refer) in
    if error != nil {
        // failed to delete post                    
    }
    else {
        // delete worked
    }
})
```